# Earning the 'Generalist' badge bug?

Tags: bug, badges

To earn the Generalist badge, one has to "Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags".

As of yesterday, I have that:

1. [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing) - 403 total score
2. [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction) - 363 total score
3. [characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) - 287 total score
4. [character-development](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) - 204 total score
5. [plot](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) - 177 total score
6. [technique](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) - 169 total score
7. [novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) - 163 total score
8. [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) - 149 total score
9. [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) - 119 total score
10. [style](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) - 112 total score
11. [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) - 66 total score
12. [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) - 55 total score
13. [viewpoint](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewpoint) - 49 total score
14. [dialogue](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) - 43 total score
15. [word-choice](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) - 34 total score
16. [description](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/description) - 33 total score
17. [editing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing) - 26 total score
18. [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) - 24 total score
19. [storyline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyline) - 23 total score
20. [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) - 22 total score

The listed 20 tags are all in the top 40, if "top 40" means "the 40 tags that have the most questions", "the 40 most popular tags". In all 20 I have a total score of more than 15 for answers provided.

So what's the issue? Why isn't the badge working?

I notice that *nobody* has been awarded this badge yet. Which is odd, considering I am hardly the most contributing member here. Is the badge awarded for something other than what it says, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one-sentence badge descriptions sometimes omit the details of how badges are awarded. The [comprehensive badge reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68258) clarifies that Generalist is

> Only awarded to anyone after each of the 40 top tags has over 200 questions

The idea is that the notion of "top 40 tags" on which the badge is based needs to be stable. When a new site has "top 40 tags" with only a handle of questions in each, it would be premature to award badges based on this order.

Granted, Writing is not a new site at all; but the criterion was set with fast-growing sites in mind. It will be a long time before Writing qualifies for Generalist badge awards.

Comment: Ah. So, considering some of those "most popular" tags currently have less than 100 questions, we're not going to see the Generalist badge for years and years yet. :(  Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @Galastel Similarly, on this Meta site we're some distance from seeing the first Electorate badge ("Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions")...

Comment: As of 12/6/18, 21 tags have over 200 questions.  All but 2 of the top 40 have over 100 questions.